# Unauthorized Access when running `azure site log tail` for a recreated site

Tags: node.js, azure, streaming, azure-web-app-service, diagnostics

I had an Azure Website that was setup and was using PHP and WordPress.
I wanted to use the same name for a site that would be running node and deployed from github, so I deleted the first site and recreated it with my new information.

Now when I try to run `azure site log tail mysite`, I get back html that basically says `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.`.

I have other Azure Websites running under this same account/subscription that work fine and I can see my `console.log` messages when running `tail`. I even have one that is deployed from the same github repo/branch, so the code isn't any different.

The only difference is that another person setup the site when it was the PHP site. But I used my account when deleting and recreating.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the website was created by another person, I suggest you reset its credentials.

1. Open the [Windows Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com).
2. Go to the website's dashboard.
3. Click on "Reset your deployment credentials" and reset the username and password.
4. Click on "Reset your publish profile credentials".
5. Click on "Download the publish profile" and configure the command-line tools with the new profile, username and password.

Comment: Thanks @fernando-correia. I ended up deleting the site and just creating one with a new name and it worked fine. To make sure your answer works, I'll create a site with the first name and see if I can get it to work with new credentials.